# Bullets only on first listed li's, not nested

Tags: html, css

I have this list that has yellow bullets on the list. But want them removed if there's a nested ul as well. Is there a way to do that CSS only?

[image: example image]

```css
   
ul.list-bullets--yellow {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 1.25rem;
    padding-left: 1.75rem;
}
ul.list-bullets--yellow li:before {
    content: "\25CF";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    color: #F2A900;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-bullets--yellow">
 <li>Lifecycle Automation – employees, contractors, business partners, RPA/bots</li>
 <li>Identity Governance controls: </li>

 // this ul li are the ones that I only want the default html bullet. not the yellow
   <ul>
    <li>Role-based access control (RBAC) model</li>
    <li>Policy model–suitability and separation of duties (SOD)</li>
   </ul>


 <li>Account and Password Management</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

this can be done by switching `ul.list-bullets--yellow li:before` to `ul.list-bullets--yellow > li:before`

This is a CSS "child selector", you can read more on them on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp). Basically the added `>` says only if the `li:before` is a direct child of `ul.list-bullets--yellow`

```css
   
ul.list-bullets--yellow {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 1.25rem;
    padding-left: 1.75rem;
}
ul.list-bullets--yellow > li:before {
    content: "\25CF";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    color: #F2A900;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-bullets--yellow">
 <li>Lifecycle Automation – employees, contractors, business partners, RPA/bots</li>
 <li>Identity Governance controls: </li>

 // this ul li are the ones that I only want the default html bullet. not the yellow
   <ul>
    <li>Role-based access control (RBAC) model</li>
    <li>Policy model–suitability and separation of duties (SOD)</li>
   </ul>


 <li>Account and Password Management</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The markup is wrong,`<ul>` must only include `<li>` So you have to nest the `<ul>` inside an  `<li>` which will make it even more trickier

Answer (score 3):

Your CSS is targeting all the `li` tags below the `ul.list-bullets--yellow` tag. you need to use the child combinator selector `>`

See https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/ for more information

```css
   
ul.list-bullets--yellow {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 1.25rem;
    padding-left: 1.75rem;
}
ul.list-bullets--yellow > li:before {
    content: "\25CF";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    color: #F2A900;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-bullets--yellow">
 <li>Lifecycle Automation – employees, contractors, business partners, RPA/bots</li>
 <li>Identity Governance controls: </li>

 // this ul li are the ones that I only want the default html bullet. not the yellow
   <ul>
    <li>Role-based access control (RBAC) model</li>
    <li>Policy model–suitability and separation of duties (SOD)</li>
   </ul>


 <li>Account and Password Management</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your markup is broken, a `<ul>` must only contain `<li>`.

The nested `<ul>` element must be put inside an `<li>` element.

With that being said, We can hide the bullet on the `<li>` which have the nest `<ul>` just by having it.

```css
[yellow] {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}

[yellow]>li {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

[yellow]>li:before {
  content: "\25CF";
  color: #F2A900;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

[nested] {
  /* So we can apply a z-index */
  position: relative;
  /* higher z-index value than the bullet*/
  z-index: 1;
  /* we can use margin here but since we have position relative why not use left */
  left: -1rem;
  /* push the nested ul so it looks nested */
  padding-left: 3rem;
  /* none-transparent background to hide the bullet*/
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<ul yellow>
  <li>Lifecycle Automation – employees, contractors, business partners, RPA/bots</li>
  <li>Identity Governance controls: </li>
  <li>
    <ul nested>
      <li>Role-based access control (RBAC) model</li>
      <li>Policy model–suitability and separation of duties (SOD)</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Account and Password Management</li>
</ul>
```

---

If you want to give the nested `<ul>` the same bullet, we can simplify the code like this.

```css
[yellow],[nested] {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}


li {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 1rem;
}


li:before {
  content: "\25CF";
  color: #F2A900;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

[nested] {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  left: -1rem;
  padding-left: 3rem;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<ul yellow>
  <li>Lifecycle Automation – employees, contractors, business partners, RPA/bots</li>
  <li>Identity Governance controls: </li>
  <li>
    <ul nested>
      <li>Role-based access control (RBAC) model</li>
      <li>Policy model–suitability and separation of duties (SOD)</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Account and Password Management</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with:

```
ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

Because here the second `ul` (without classes) got the default styling for each `li`. You may also set `li { list-style: none; }`, but if you have ordered lists somewhere it could break something. Of course, margins and paddings have the same issue.